# Why I can't change button to be rounded button?

Tags: android

I created **xml** file on the resource - name of the file **button_shape.xml** ( android studio added this file to **res/values** )

I add this code to the **xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#2D8CD6"
        android:endColor="#2D8CD6"
        android:angle="270"/>

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp"/>
</shape>
</resources>
```

( If I remove the  from the xml => i getting an error )

Now, I add this to the code

```
<Button
        android:text="Start"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        />
```

but i getting an error on the

"android:background="@drawable/button_shape""

The android studio does not allow me to change the xml location to be under the 'drawable'

1. What I did wrong?
2. How to change simple button to be rounded button?

Comment: if you want to create your own background you should create a selector in drawable folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how to create custom button with corners and effects 
here is the code.
first Create a xml file in your drawable folder such as button.xml and paste the following :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
         <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#345953" android:endColor="#689a92"  />            
     </shape>
 </item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
         <solid android:color="#58857e"/>       
     </shape>
 </item>  
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
         <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e" />            
     </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

**Second use following drawable for the background of your button**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="Buttons" />
```

Answer (score 2):

move `button_shape.xml` to drawable folder

then remove `<resources>` and `</resources>` of this file

and edit this line remove `>` at the end of the first line

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    android:shape="rectangle">
```

I hope that help you

Answer (score 2):

Add this XMl in **Drawable** folder

**round_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ffb5a6"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ffeddd"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

call the xml

```
  <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your drawable xml file. Replace

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:shape="rectangle">
```

with

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
```

Removing the closing '>' from the first line. Try it then.